# Running Nant 0.86 in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: .net, nant, windows-server-2008-r2

Hi i'm trying to run Nant but keep getting this error when i tried to build

Failed to initialize the 'Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5' target framework
   Property evaluation failed
   Expression:$>
   Property 'sdkInstallRoot' has not been set

I have .Net framework 4.0 running previously is 3.5;is there a work around for this?What do i need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an NAnt configuration problem - for the target framework "net-3.5", the "sdkInstallRoot" property is being read from a non-existent Registry key.

The details may vary based on your server and its configuration, but in general you will need to a) ensure that the appropriate .NET and Windows SDKs are installed on your server, and b) that NAnt.exe.config properly references the Registry.

Look in your config file for the `<framework>` section with the name "net-3.5".  Inside of that element, there is another element called `<project>`.  It defines the properties `installRoot` and the problematic `sdkInstallRoot`.  Version 0.86 does not use the registry keys applicable to Vista and later operating systems.  The actual SDK installation folder key could be one of a few names - use `regedit.exe` to find out.

On my machine, for instance, sdkInstallRoot is defined as:

```
<readregistry
    property="sdkInstallRoot"
    key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK\InstallationFolder"
    hive="LocalMachine"
    failonerror="false" />
```

Verify that the registry key as named exists, and if not, correct your config file.  That *should* fix your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You give the latest version of NAnt a try. Current version is 0.91-alpha2 (August 17, 2010). As the [release notes](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91-alpha2/releasenotes.html) state, support for .NET 4.0 has been added in 0.91-alpha1 (May 29, 2010). Don't worry about alpha status. We're using this version in our production environment without any problems.